# shl instruction throws 'error A2070 : invalid instruction operands'

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I am learning Assembly Programming Language, and I've started using macros to shorten my program. One of the macro isn't working as expected.

This the bare bone program I am trying to run,

```
include pcmac.inc

.model small

.stack 100h

.data

.code

Hello PROC
    _Begin     ;Line 12
    _Exit 0
Hello ENDP

END Hello
```

Inside the `pcmac.inc` file the `_Begin` macro has the following definition,

```
_Begin  MACRO
        mov     ax, @data
        mov     ds, ax
        mov     bx, ss
        sub     bx, ax
        shl     bx, 4
        mov     ss, ax
        add     sp, bx
        ENDM
```

When I run this program I get the following error,

```
file.asm(12) : error A2070 : invalid instruction operands
    _Begin(5)   :   Macro Called From
    file.asm(12):   Main Line Code
```

If I replace `_Begin` macro with the original assembly code, the program works as expected,

```
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
```

Can anyone tell me why the `_Begin` macro isn't working, and what does the error mean?

I am using masm on Windows 8 on iMac.

---

**Edit:**
I've just found that if I comment out the following line in the `_Begin` macro the program works.

```
shl     bx, 4
```

But this PCMAC.INC file is provided by the book we are following for the class, and we aren't supposed to modify this file.

Comment: Assuming that line 12 refers to the `mov ax, @data` instruction, my suspicion is that the macro expands into an instruction form where you pass operands incorrectly. Looks like you want to pass an immediate integer value `5`. I think that needs a `$` or `#` something to denote "immediate" value. Check the manual for your assembler.

Comment: You wrote that the file name is pamac.inc but then included `include pcmac.inc`, is it your actual code is there a mistake in your post?

Comment: @MByD Sorry it was a typo. Fixed it.

Comment: @Jens Line 12 refers to _Begin macro. And I think line 5 referrers to a line inside the _Begin macro. I am just started learning. I am not sure what immediate value is. And the PCMAC.INC files was provided by the book we are following - we aren't supposed to modify this file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`shl bx, 4` causes the error. To shift with a shift count larger than 1 was introduced with the 80186 processor. MASM accepts by default only 8086 instructions, but you can direct it to accept later instruction sets.

TL;DR: Place a `.186` directive to the top of the source. Better is `.386`.